# Webpack + TypeScript: Module not found

Tags: typescript, webpack, umd

I'm trying to use an npm package called [`@soil/dom`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@soil/dom) via webpack, by simply doing:

```
import {h} from '@soil/dom'
```

But when running `webpack`, I get these warning and error:

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/@soil/dom/build/index.js 3:24-31
Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted
 @ ./src/index.ts

ERROR in ./node_modules/@soil/dom/build/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './html/h' in '/home/daniel/Code/time-flies/node_modules/@soil/dom/build'
 @ ./node_modules/@soil/dom/build/index.js 7:8-70
 @ ./src/index.ts
```

My `package.json` file looks like this:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@soil/dom": "0.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "2.9.1",
    "ts-loader": "4.4.1",
    "webpack": "4.12.0",
    "webpack-cli": "3.0.3"
  }
}
```

My `webpack.config.js` file looks like this:

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: './src/index.ts',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

On the `@soil/dom` side of things, the directory structure of the npm package looks like this:

```
@soil/
└── dom
    ├── build
    │   ├── html
    │   │   ├── h.js
    │   │   └── ...
    │   ├── index.js
    │   └── ...
    ├── package.json
    └── ...
```

The `package.json` contains:

```
{
    "main": "build/index.js"
}
```

And the `index.js` file contains (it's been compiled targeting the UMD module system):

```
var h_1 = require("./html/h");
exports.h = h_1.h;
```

Why isn't webpack able to resolve the relative path `'./html/h'` at this point? What is missing in this picture?